# Why my editing still alive in the work dir after I do cleanall for the recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I am trying to debug a recipe, flexbe-mirror in the yocto. by the way, I found a strange things that I had understood.

I have understood all working contents are removed after `bitbake -c cleanall flexbe-mirror` and build contents are renewed when I do `bitbake flexbe-mirror` even if I had modified a content of work dir, `tmp/work/armv8-poky-linux/flexbe-mirror/2.3.3-1-r0`.
And I checked all contents in the `tmp/work/armv8-poky-linux/flexbe-mirror/2.3.3-1-r0` are gone.

I had modified a file by adding new print for debugging, `tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/flexbe-mirror/2.3.3-1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/installer/utils.py`. then, I did `bitbake -c cleanall flexbe-mirror` again. But, I found my modification still alive even I did `bitbake -c cleanall flexbe-mirror`.

Here is my modification:
[image]

And build logs after do cleanall:
[image]

I checked whether recipe-sysroot-native is symbolic link or not and it is real path.

I expect it should be cleared and renew all contents as well as initial state before I modify it.

I hope to get any explanation I can understand why.

Thanks in advance.

BR,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

`cleanall` chains to `clean` which essentially does `rm -rf ${WORKDIR}`.

The recipe sysroots are hardlink farm (not copies, as that would be incredibly slow).  Your editor is most likely not breaking hardlinks when it writes a new file, so you've been editing the master copy of that file in sysroot-components.

You can restore the file by doing `bitbake python3-installer-native -C unpack` to force it to re-build.